# Connect CI Runner to Docker network

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following configuration:

- dockered gitlab (named gitlab)
- dockered gitlab-ci-multirunner (linked to gitlab and named gitlab-runners).

```
       ┌──────────────────────┐  ┌─────────┐
       │      172.12.x.x      │  │172.13.x.│
      ┌┴──────────┬┬──────────┴┐┌┴─────────┴┐
      │  GitLab   ││  GitLab   ││  GitLab   │
      │           ││  Runners  ││  Runners  │
      │           ││           ││           │
      └───────────┘└───────────┘└───────────┘
           │            │    │    ▲
           │            │    │   ╱
           │            │    │  ╱
           │            │    ▼ ╱
    ───────┴────────────┴────────────────────
```

I successfully registered a runner into gitlab, but when I try to run a build I cannot manage to connect the docker container of the project spawned by the gitlab-runners to my gitlab docker; therefore when the project docker tries to clone the project it's not able to resolve the name http://gitlab/ I tried to use the parameter `-links=["network-name:gitlab"]` in the toml file of my runner, but this leads to:

```
API error (500) Could not get container for <network name>.
```

Any clues?

Here is my .toml:

concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

```
  [[runners]]
  name = "d4cf95ba5a90"
  url = "http://gitlab/ci"
  token = "9e6c2edb5832f92512a69df1ec4464"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "node:4.2.2"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    links = ["evci_default:gitlab"]
  [runners.cache]
```

Answer (score 1):

Only one solution i found is to add IP of docker host to 'extra_hosts' of config.toml

extra_hosts = ["host:192.168.137.1"]